# Define a function pointer with typedef in a class to a parent class function

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

Im trying to convert the Piconomic HDLC C -module to C++ Class.

http://www.piconomic.co.za/fwlib/hdlc_8h_source.html
http://www.piconomic.co.za/fwlib/hdlc_8c_source.html

Im having trouble passing function pointers from a Qt programs **MainWindow class to the HDLC class**.
Function pointer could be passed in the HDLC hdlc_init function or to the HDLC HDLC constructor that takes those parameters.

Assuming we have MainWindow and HDLC -classes, how to change these to point to

```
MainWindow::putChar(char data) and
MainWindow::onRxFrame(const u8_t *buffer, u16_t bytes_received)

class HDLC {
/**
   Definition for a pointer to a function that will be called to 
   send a character
 */
typedef void (*hdlc_put_char_t)(char data);

/**
   Definition for a pointer to a function that will be called once a frame 
   has been received.
 */
typedef void (*hdlc_on_rx_frame_t)(const u8_t *buffer, u16_t bytes_received);
}
void hdlc_init(hdlc_put_char_t    put_char,
                      hdlc_on_rx_frame_t on_rx_frame);
}


// HDLC.cpp:
/// Pointer to the function that will be called to send a character
static hdlc_put_char_t    hdlc_put_char;

/// Pointer to the function that will be called to handle a received HDLC frame
static hdlc_on_rx_frame_t hdlc_on_rx_frame;

void HDLC::hdlc_init(hdlc_put_char_t    put_char,
               hdlc_on_rx_frame_t on_rx_frame)
{
    hdlc_rx_frame_index = 0;
    hdlc_rx_frame_fcs   = HDLC_INITFCS;
    hdlc_rx_char_esc    = FALSE;
    hdlc_put_char       = put_char;
    hdlc_on_rx_frame    = on_rx_frame;
}
```

Can this even be done like this, that HDLC is given a pointer to MainWindow class function?

Comment: A non-static member function cannot be converted to a regular function pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can typedef your function as:

```
typedef std::function<void(char)> hdlc_put_char_t;
```

Then to pass MainWindow class function pointer you can use [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), for example:

```
MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow;
hdlc.hdlc_init(std::bind(&MainWindow::someFun, mw), ...);
```

It is because class member function pointers need an object on which they are invoked on.

Comment: This is probably a good choice for plain C++ program. But I just realized that when using Qt you can achieve the same end result by turning all receiving functions to SLOT’s and all calls of external functions to emit SIGNAL. `emit hdlc_on_rx_frame(hdlc_rx_frame, (quint16)(hdlc_rx_frame_index-2));` [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html]

Comment: True, in Qt signal / slot mechanism is preferable than function pointers. Good that you solved it :)